# Using the nebula.os-package plugin, how to specify package architecture

Tags: gradle, rpm, netflix-nebula-plugins

I'm building a native code package with the nebula.os-package plugin for gradle.  I need to specify that glibc of the correct architecture is a requirement.  I tried the obvious

```
requires 'glibc%{?_isa}'
```

but then rpm -qpR foo.rpm unhelpfully results in

```
glibc%{?_isa}
```

Using `%{_isa}` without the question mark is no different.

Open issues [136](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin/issues/136) and [227](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin/issues/227) in the gitHub repo are about this, but no maintainer has commented in those threads.  Has anybody found a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quote; you're telling `rpmbuild` *not* to parse variables within the string.

For your future knowledge, the leading `?` means "it's OK if this variable doesn't exist; just don't use it."